# Elasticearch need to return only one language text

Tags: elasticsearch

mapping:

```
PUT /test
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "product_id": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "product_name": {
                "type": "nested",
                "include_in_parent": true,
                "properties": {
                    "lang_id": {
                        "type": "byte"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Insert some data:

```
POST /test/_doc
{
    "product_id": 111,
    "product_name": [
        {
            "lang_id": 1,
            "name": "one"
        },
        {
            "lang_id": 2,
            "name": "ein"
        }
    ]
}

POST /test/_doc
{
    "product_id": 222,
    "product_name": [
        {
            "lang_id": 1,
            "name": "two"
        },
        {
            "lang_id": 2,
            "name": "zwei"
        }
    ]
}
```

My query for return the lang_id = 2, name = 'ein' document:

```
POST /test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "product_name",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "product_name.name": "ein"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "product_name.lang_id": 2
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "_source": [
        "product_id",
        "product_name"
    ]
}
```

The result:

```
...
                "_source": {
                    "product_id": 111,
                    "product_name": [
                        {
                            "lang_id": 1,
                            "name": "one"
                        },
                        {
                            "lang_id": 2,
                            "name": "ein"
                        }
                    ]
                }
...
```

Visibel at it returns all product_names, but I need only the name with lang_id =2 (ein)

My solution is:

```
POST /test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "product_name",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "product_name.name": "ein"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "product_name.lang_id": 2
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "_source": [
        "product_id"
    ],
    "script_fields": {
        "selected_name": {
            "script": {
                "source": "def name_langid = 0;for (int i = 0; i < params._source.product_name.length; i++) {if (params._source.product_name[i].lang_id == params.langid) {name_langid = params._source.product_name[i].name;}}name_langid;",
                "params": {
                    "langid": 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which returns the expected result:

```
...
                "_source": {
                    "product_id": 111
                },
                "fields": {
                    "selected_name": [
                        "ein"
                    ]
                }
...
```

But I think it is not the best solution, because scripting maybe slow down the query.

Is there any simpler solution to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

### `filter_path` can help you.

> All REST APIs accept a `filter_path` parameter that can be used to
> reduce the response returned by Elasticsearch. This parameter takes a
> comma separated list of filters expressed with the dot notation:
> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering

```
POST /test/_search?filter_path=**.product_name
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "product_name",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "product_name.name": "ein"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "product_name.lang_id": 2
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "product_id",
    "product_name"
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's not what filter_path is for. What I need is not to return product_name in all languages, but only the one that was in the filter. This is what I want to see:
"product_name": [
                        {
                            "lang_id": 2,
                            "name": "ein"
                        }
                    ]

Comment: Thanks, Now I understand the case, The best way to get only `"product_name": [ { "lang_id": 2, "name": "ein" } ]` from  `"product_name": [
            {
              "lang_id": 1,
              "name": "one"
            },
            {
              "lang_id": 2,
              "name": "ein"
            }
          ]` is a custom script like you did. The other method is manipulate the data to have only lang_id: 2.

Answer (score 0):

Please, read

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits

and

[How to fetch only specific object inside nested field along with search query in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66579117/how-to-fetch-only-specific-object-inside-nested-field-along-with-search-query-in)

I guess your query transforms into

```
 POST /test/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source,hits.hits.inner_hits
    {
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "product_name",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "product_name.name": "ein"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "product_name.lang_id": 2
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "inner_hits": {
            "_source": [
              "product_name.name"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "_source": [
        "product_id"
      ]
    }
```

I use the filter_path parameter to shorten a response

The response is

```
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_source" : {
          "product_id" : 111
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "product_name" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 2.1469178,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "test",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "o9sVmY0BjkcaB7x6XFH6",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "product_name",
                    "offset" : 1
                  },
                  "_score" : 2.1469178,
                  "_source" : {
                    "name" : "ein"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It isn't the expected result, but without scripting